# Confusing question on finding mean from frequency tables.

Tags: average, means

[image]

My attempt:

The missing frequency = 6 (from 50 games which represents total 
frequency)

Total number of tickets won by Adan = 203

Mean number of tickets won per game = $\frac{203}{50}=4.06$

From this point onwards I am lost, especially when I read this part of 
the question ' Aidan wants to exchange his ticket for a prize that costs 
800 tickets. How many more games do you expect Aidan would have to 
play?'

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Basic approach.** The question is worded a little oddly.  I would at least have expected it to put "tickets" in the plural in that third sentence.

Be that as it may, I read it as asking how many further games do you expect Aidan to have to play—winning tickets at his current pace per game—to total $800$ tickets.  I'm going to assume that you have correctly computed his current ticket total at $203$, in which case he needs $800-203 = 597$ more tickets.  I will also assume that you've correctly computed his average ticket rate per game at $4.06$.

So the question is, how many games would he have to play, winning $4.06$ tickets per game, to win $597$ more tickets?

Answer (score 1):

So he has played $50$ games already and amassed $203$ tickets. Then the number of games he is expected to play to get the $800$ tickets is the number of games it will take to get $597$ tickets. This is found by $\frac{597}{4.06} = 147.044$ but we want to round up because we assume we can't have an incomplete game, so the answer is he needs to play $148$ more games to amass the $597$ extra tickets to get to $800$